# How to stop audio from playing in my C game?

Tags: c, audio

I'm making a game in C and I wanted to change from one audio file to another, but I have to wait for the first file to finish playing. Is there a way to make the first one stop playing right away?

This is my code:

```
void MusicPlayer (){
    while (music == true)
        PlaySound("elevat_loop1.wav" , NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    while (music == false)
        PlaySound("silence.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
    if (music == true)
        MusicPlayer();
}

thread t(MusicPlayer);//I used thread because I want music to play independently
```

I want the first file to stop from playing without having to wait.
I tried using SND_ASYNC, but the sound won't play if I do so.

Comment: C, but you have objects? What is `Playsound`?

Comment: i think he means the mmsystem playsound

Comment: The PlaySound function plays a sound specified by the given file name.

Comment: check this :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44960898/make-audio-resume-after-being-stopped

Comment: This `thread t(MusicPlayer);` doesn't look like C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. The code is

```
void MusicPlayer (){
    if (music == true)
        PlaySound(TEXT("elevmus.wav"), NULL, SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
    while (music == true)
        ;
    if (music == false)
        PlaySound("silence.wav", NULL, SND_LOOP | SND_ASYNC);
    while (music == false)
        ;
    if (music == true)
        MusicPlayer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

may be execute *PlaySound* in an other thread and when needed kill that thread ?

---

out of that

```
void MusicPlayer (){
  while (music == true)
    PlaySound("elevat_loop1.wav" , NULL, SND_FILENAME);
  while (music == false)
    PlaySound("silence.wav", NULL, SND_FILENAME);
  if (music == true)
    MusicPlayer();
}
```

Does recursion for nothing, even may be the compiler will optimize it seems better to use a loop

`while (music == false) {...}` will give hand when *music* is back true, so `if (music == true)` have a great chance to be true, is it really needed to test it ?

Comment: I use the last test because I want to go back to looping "elevat_loop1.wav". I tried to use SND_ASYNC that should return immediately instead of blocking while the sound is played, but if I use SND_ASYNC, the sound won't play.